# Is it inappropriate to contact the hiring manager if a candidate's timeline is extremely short?

Tags: job-offer

I interviewed a couple weeks ago (let's call them Alpha Co) and was told last Friday that they're on the next step, the background and reference check. So it sounds like they'd proceed with an offer once that clears.

Late last Thursday, I was given an offer for an internal transfer (let's call them Bravo Co). The offer expires today, and it doesn't look like they'll let me kick the decision down to, say, the end of this week. The offer is OK, but nothing to write home about.

I'd much prefer working at Alpha than Bravo from a career standpoint, and it does sound like an offer is coming. But the fear is, by the time Alpha gets back to me the offer for Bravo will have passed, *and* Alpha's offer would have been worse.

I emailed the HR manager and the hiring manager to give full disclosure yesterday about the other offer on the table, and have not received a response yet.

Is it inappropriate to call up the hiring manager and get an idea of what kind of timeline we're looking at, or where I am in their process?

Comment: If you do not accept the internal transfer will you still have the same role? If so at least that is the fall back position

Comment: @EdHeal Yes, however I am moving to a new geographical location (wife got a new job). So while I can stick around in my current position for a little while (say, 6 months) while searching for a new position in the new area, long-term I can't stay where I am.

Comment: Is the internal job in the new location? If not it is not much use anyway. Is the potential new job in the right location? If not it is not much use either.

Comment: @EdHeal both positions are in the new location.

Comment: Why would accepting the internal transfer preclude you from accepting the external offer a week or three later?

Comment: @DanPichelman I didn't think of that. That strikes me as somewhat unprofessional, however. If I accept the internal transfer they'd tell everybody on the list behind me "OK, we filled it, sorry, no offer for you", just for me to cut-and-run less than a month later?

Comment: As it is close to xmas, ask very politely about the internal position can you tell them in the new year. At this time of year I would imagine another week or so should not matter

Comment: I would not think that it is nice to take the internal position then resign within a week. You might need a reference from your current employer (In the UK it is the last two employers you usually get a reference from).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accept the internal transfer.  If you get the external offer a month later, review your options then.

Reasons:

1. It's better than your current job.
2. The external offer might fall through. (External company might get purchased, senior management may impose a hiring freeze, they may change their mind, etc.)

If you do accept the external offer, management will shrug their shoulders, wish you well, then call whoever was their 2nd choice.  It's a hassle on their end, but all part of doing business.

There is nothing "not nice" or "unprofessional" about looking out for your own best interests.

Comment: I mostly agree, although you have to consider that taking the transfer and then quitting soon after might end up "burning bridges" at the old company. Internal transfers can be just as resource-intensive as new hires, especially when it involves resource allocations within the new team/department.

Comment: It's now 1 week later, and I took the internal transfer. I was lucky that I was able to get an extension to accept the transfer, and it looks like Alpha Co was never going to be able to meet my salary requirements (despite stringing me along for a while).